# Click on button in listItem does not respond on first click, but response on second click, how to set to response on first click?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, onclicklistener, listitem

I have ListView, and everubody listItem have a button.
I cant get event on first click on imageView, but after first when I click second time I get Event. Why I cant get response on first click on imageView?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {      
        ImageView addLarge =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.addLargeImage);
        ImageView addSmall =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.addSmallImage);
        addLarge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                addProductToCart = true;
                addToOrderListClick = true;
                OrderProduct order = new OrderProduct(listProductId.get(position), listProductName.get(position), 
                        listProductNameEn.get(position), listProductImageUrl.get(position), "large", listProductPriceLarge.get(position));
                orderListProduct.add(order);
                animCopyListItemAddToCart(view, position, mainRelativeLaout);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "AddLarge", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        addSmall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                addProductToCart = true;
                addToOrderListClick = true;
                OrderProduct order = new OrderProduct(listProductId.get(position), listProductName.get(position), 
                        listProductNameEn.get(position), listProductImageUrl.get(position), "small", listProductPriceSmall.get(position));
                orderListProduct.add(order);
                animCopyListItemAddToCart(view, position, mainRelativeLaout);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "addSmall", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting your onClickListener() for your ImageViews within your ListView onItemClickListener().

So the user selects an item in your list, and only then does an onClickListener for your ImageViews get assigned. So the second time, the onclick listener of the ImageView gets successfully fired.

To navigate around this issue, assign the individual ImageView onClickListeners within a custom adapter so they are assigned when they come into view as opposed to when a user clicks an item in list.

Comment: assign the individual ImageView onClickListeners within a custom adapter is not good solution for my app,because in that case I don't get what I want. I wish implement onClickListener in onItemClickListener if it possible ?